# Integral over slowly varying function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $g(x)$ is a function with $\int_0^\infty|g(x)|<\infty$. If $\mathcal{L}(x)$ is a slowly varying function at infinity, does is hold that
$$ \int_0^\infty g(x)d\mathcal{L}(x)\sim \int_0^\infty g(x)dx?$$
Intuitively, since $\mathcal{L}(x)$ is slowly varying, these two should be similar I guess, but I have not been able to find anything relating the two, so maybe it is just incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sim$?

Comment: I hoped that they would be similar (so for example an additive or multiplicative error term),but the answer below already shows that there is no hope of such a thing to hold in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take, for example, $\mathcal L(x)=\log(x)$ and $g(x)=x^{-2}$ for $x\ge1$. Then
$$
\int_1^\infty g(x)d\mathcal L(x)=\int_1^\infty x^{-2}d\log(x)=\int_1^\infty x^{-2}x^{-1}dx\ne\int_1^\infty x^{-2}dx.
$$
We can take $g(x)=x^{-1}$ for $x\ge1$. Then the integral on the right hand side would not even converge.